# Cloned Repo is broken/behaving strangely but works for others

Tags: github

I was given access to a repository on Github, and when I clone it every thing seems fine.  However, some rails commands aren't recognized.  Calling Rails server gives me this: 
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice

.
.
.
And it keeps going with several options.

Additionally, git status lists the changes to be committed and there are many (if not all) files listed as deleted.

I have read/write access to the repo and I've tried cloning it in several different ways into several different places but no luck.  Also others are cloning just fine.  Any ideas?

Edit: Using windows

Comment: to reset everything to the original state, reset the local modifications with `git reset --hard`

Comment: How is configured your `core.autocrlf` option ? Check using `git config core.autocrlf`

Comment: trying to use the hard reset give me fatal: cannot create directory at 'db/...timestamp': invalid argument

Comment: git config core.autocrlf simply returns 'false'